# How to compute the following equation correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, math

Using python 2.7 I am trying to compute the following rather difficult set of equations.

[image]

I have successfully implemented the first two, but am struggling with the third. Here is my attempt,

```
def pi_tau( r ):
    return (1 - (1 - r)**(t + 1))/(2 - r)  

def mean_field( r ): 
    return 1 - (1 - r)**t

def pi_neighbour( r ):
    inside = []
    for kappa_dash in range(0, kappa - 1):

        Binomial_Coefficient = (math.factorial(kappa - 1)) / (math.factorial(kappa - 1 - kappa_dash)*math.factorial(kappa_dash))          

        top = ((mean_field( r )*pi_tau( r ))**kappa_dash)*(1 - mean_field( r )*pi_tau( r ))**(kappa - 1 - kappa_dash)

        bottom = kappa_dash + 1

    fraction = top/bottom
    inside.append(kappa_dash)
    inside[kappa_dash] = inside[kappa_dash] + fraction*Binomial_Coefficient

return pi_tau*inside
```

I then try to call this function

```
# set parameters 
r = 0.15
kappa = 2.1
T = 10

ppp_t = []
mmm_f = []
nnn_t = []

for t in range(0, T):
    ppp_t.append(pi_tau( r ))
    mmm_f.append(mean_field( r ))
    nnn_t.append(pi_neighbour( r ))
```

I get the following error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-41-9bcf462306f0> in <module>()


   6     ppp_t.append(pi_tau( r ))
      7     mmm_f.append(mean_field( r ))
----> 8     nnn_t.append(pi_neighbour( r ))

<ipython-input-39-d9acdd7490f9> in pi_neighbour(r)
     19         inside[kappa_dash] = inside[kappa_dash] + fraction*Binomial_Coefficient
     20 
---> 21     return pi_tau*inside

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'function'
```

I am looking for any advice on how to implement the third function and improve on my method.

Comment: You might put the names of the equations within the title and question text, so others searching might find them easier. Title, for instance, "Compute name1, name, name3 in Python" or something.

Comment: `pi_tau` is a function, not a number. Did you mean to call `pi_tau`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several weird things here:

- you calculate the top, bottom, and bionomial all in the `for` loop, but don't **sum up in that `for` loop**; and
- you multiply the `pi_tau` **function** with a list?

  ```
  return pi_tau*inside
  ```
- you use `range(0, kappa - 1)`, but the **upperbound of `range(..)` is exclusive**

Nevertheless, you make things quite hard. You could use the following approach:

```
from math import factorial

def pi_neighbour(r):
    sum = 0.0
    for kappa_dash in range(0,kappa):
        bin_coeff = factorial(kappa-1)/(factorial(kappa-1-kappa_dash)*factorial(kappa_dash))      
        top = ((mean_field(r)*pi_tau(r))**kappa_dash)*(1-mean_field(r)*pi_tau(r))**(kappa-1-kappa_dash)
        sum += bin_coeff*top/(kappa_dask+1)
    return pi_tau(r)*sum
```

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you meant to do is the following in line 21 of the traceback:

```
return pi_tau(r)*inside
```

You forgot to call the function, and so it is attempting to multiply an integer by a **function**, rather than the **return value of the function**.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are multiplying a list, that is `inside` and a integer, that is `return of pi_tau(r)`

Do this instead (a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html))

try this:

`return [i*pi_tau(r) for i in inside]`